# Strange Behavior in SceneKit Debug Options

Tags: debugging, scenekit, physics-engine

I sometimes switch ON the debug-options' visibility of physicsShapes (which I apply to enable collisions in my game app).
One of the starting scenes is an island with a cave entrance, surrounded by a SCNKit Floornode which (at this point in time) depicts the ocean.
The strange behavior that I found is that upon switching the ocean-floor's visibility to OFF (in the Nodes inspector), the physicsShapes (if switched ON) suddenly are shown from a top camera view - and detached from the actual nodes which shapes they represent.
And even more strange - the collision detection is still entirely working, which means that the visible presentations of the physicsShapes are detached from the physicsShapes themselves, too...

In short:

ocean-floor (OFF) + debugPhysShape (ON) --> physicsShapes from top perspective

ocean-floor (ON) + debugPhysShape (ON) --> normal view

ocean-floor (ON) + debugPhysShape (OFF) --> normal view

ocean-floor (OFF) + debugPhysShape (OFF) --> normal view

I am wondering if this is some kind of function that is accidentally activated, or if it is a bug?